# Azure Functions Blob Trigger for all containers

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage

I have a multi-tenant app where I store all my tenants in one azure storage account with each tenant having their own blob.

So things are structured like this:

```
 /1c77e308-d6f0-4c40-ac26-4bb6322d06ac/d3c6311e-05dd-4292-a2a5-31ab453cec76/somefile.png
```

This represents a `/{tenantId}/{entityId}/{file}`.

I am trying to create an azure function that captures this into a db but I can't seem to get a path correct to handle this.

This is what I have currently

```cs
 [Function("AddAttachmentToDb")]
    public static void Run([BlobTrigger("{accountId}/{entityId}/{name}", Connection = "StorageConnection")] string myBlob, string name,
        string accountId, string entityId,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
        var logger = context.GetLogger("BlobTriggerCSharp");
        logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {myBlob}");
        
    }
```

How do I get this correct?

Comment: So, in your storage account you have a container per tenant ({accountId}), Inside those containers are blobs with this pattern: {entityId}/{name} (d3c6311e-05dd-4292-a2a5-31ab453cec76/somefile.png) ?

Comment: Correct. I am trying to capture anytime a file is uploaded to any tenant. Should I have taken a different structure?

Comment: Well, from the docs *A container name can't contain a resolver in the name pattern.* so if {accountId} is your container that is not going to work probably.

Comment: I get it for sure and I can refactor it over time, I will have to come up with a plan to organize it better because I have a few TB of data in there now.